# Eclipse SDK 3.2.X An error has occurred. see the log file

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, file, logging

I recently downloaded eclipse SDK 3.2 and after extract it (doesn't matter where) and trying execute I receive this message: An error has occurred. see the log file ....

The last time the log file content was:

```
!SESSION 2014-01-29 08:30:40.368 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=es_AR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY system.bundle 4 0 2014-01-29 08:30:41.439
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:1010)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:966)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:991)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:991)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:966)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-01-29 08:30:41.508
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
!SESSION Wed Jan 29 08:30:41 ART 2014 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.launcher 4 0 2014-01-29 08:30:41.537
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:186)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

I Tried with several versions 3.2.1, 3.2.2 but I always have this problem and I don't understand why.
Then I decided to try with standard versions of eclipse and ran all of it with no problems.
I reinstall all java packages again and nothing changes.
I really need to use this particular versions for work so I hope you can help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance!

PS: OS : Windows 7 64bits Home basic. workspace folder is empty (C:\Users\\workspace).

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a 2006 release rather than what's current?

Comment: My partner is using this version since 2 or more years ago. I recently start working with this and I'm trying to copy her environment to get used to it and try to update mine.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when you unzipped it? Does your user login have full rights to where it was unzipped?

Comment: No, I have no problem unzipping it (I don't get any message then). the problem appears later, I mean, when I want to use it (execute it). it just show the splash logo (Eclipse 3.2.x) and then just close and show that message. I have installed Eclipse SDK 3.8 in Ubuntu, my other OS and its configuration is in another partition with other filesystem (ext4 vs NTFS) plus is invisible from windows.I mean, I thought that this could have to be related with several configurations or workspaces existing in the same machine, but it seems is not.

Comment: I'd suggest just trying to start with the current version, Kepler SR1.

Comment: Hi again! after try and retry and a little bit more of research, I found that eclipse SDK 3.2 only support java runtime environment 1.4.2 (1.4.2_06 exactly).So I download it, install it and its working now :D . [link](http://www.oldapps.com/java.php?old_java=10?download)

Comment: @nitind Thank you very much for your help! let me know if I can vote your answers or something